# CSS float issue FF only(I think)

Tags: css

I'm having a weird float problem on my site in firefox.

[pianocourse](http://www.pianocourse.co.uk/soundintheclouds/composer/listen/)

The meta and tweet link should appear at the bottom of the modules. There are floated elements prior to the div.meta

Have tried 
overflow: auto
clear: both

Possibly a syntax problem I havent spotted. If anyone can have a look.. Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to have the meta in a div outside the module div?

Comment: Wow, your code is just awful. Do you realise you're actually giving IE 2 different `<html>` tags and one of them is inside the `<head>`? You have WAY to many useless scripts, most in the wrong place. You have classes that llok like IDs. You really should consider starting again from scratch and trying something simpler - because it looks to me like you've just copied and pasted a bunch of code from different places and now you're surprised it's acting strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is a bit odd... try putting the meta div inside the bigger div and restyle and rethink the meta-divs layout. That would probably put you off in a better position to fix these errors later on.

I made a quick fiddle, demonstrating how it could be done instead. It's not perfect but it gives you a hint. Also, don't do as I do and use inline styling, I used it for speeds sake.

[Fiddle found here](http://jsfiddle.net/SX8fz/4/)